# Structuring contract solution in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set

I am currently building a contracting solution for my business.
The contracting solution should be able the following relationships between clients, project and contracts:

- A client typically has 1 or more projects
- A project always relates to a single client
- A single contract can relate to all projects of a client **OR** to specific project(s) of a client

The basic setup is a simple library which uses a document set for each client. This document set can hold contracts, statements of work etc. Now where I am struggling is when a client has different projects. These projects are currently just folders in the "Client" document set. This in itself is not ideal since the metadata does not match between these levels.
Additionally and more crucially, a single contract for a client can also be applicable for some (not all) of the projects of that client, whereas other contracts are relevant on a project level.

I need some advice on how I would best structure this. Some options I thought about myself:

1. Add a hyperlink to the metadata of the project folder. This solution is a bit cumbersome
2. Create a seperate library with all the contracts, use a lookup column to the metadata of a project to select the correct contract. This is a bit cumbersome to keep up-to-date.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to clearly define the relationships between Clients, Projects, and Contracts. You drop a few hints but there's ambiguity. Anyone who tries to answer this is going to have to infer those relationships, and will probably make incorrect assumptions. In my world, a client can have many projects, but contracts relate to a single project. A project can have multiple contracts, but not multiple active contracts at the same time.

Comment: @DerekGussof Thank you for kindly pointing out this ambiguity. I have highlighted these relationships in my opening post. In short, each clients can have one or more projects. Each project has one or more related active contracts. Each contract can relate to one, multiple or all projects of a single client. However, all other documents (statement of work etc.) only relate to a single project.